# Create list of image pairs in tensor flow using GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensor flow and I would like to perform the following task

image1 = image, 
image2 = image,
.
.

pairs = [[image1,image2],[image1,image3],...]

How can I achieve this with tensor flow on GPU?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, I feel like you could use some kind of permutation function in python. Not necessarily tensorflow related. If misunderstood I suggest clarifying your question.